# Silent Command for LocalDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation

I would like to know if anyone knows to tell me what are the silent command to install SQL Express 2012 LocalDB (not the entire sql) and doSQLSysClrTypes.msi

Well I've tried everyone I know and found on the internet like: / Q / SP- / VERYSILENT / SUPPRESSMSGBOXES / S / SILENT / QUIET

I tried them separately and together.

Thank you

Comment: SO is solutioning for programming problems site. You may need to post in Server fault or something similar to get response.

Comment: I understood, I'll check this question out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppSetupName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppVerName={#MyAppSetupName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppCopyright=Copyright © 2007-2015 abc-dev
VersionInfoVersion={#MyAppVersion}
VersionInfoCompany=abc-dev
AppPublisher=abc-dev
;AppPublisherURL=http://...
;AppSupportURL=http://...
;AppUpdatesURL=http://...
OutputBaseFilename={#MyAppSetupName}-{#MyAppVersion}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppSetupName}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppSetupName}
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\AppInstaladorDB.exe
```